# JList with a togglable header?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to create a list that has a header, just like a JTable, that allows me to click it to change the sort order, etc. But I also want the cells of the list to be arbitrary, different sizes.

I'm able to create a JList with arbitrary-size cells or a JTable with fixed-size cells and a header, but I can't get both at the same time. I also looked into putting a JList into a JScrollPane and setting the header on the JScrollPane to a JTableHeader, but as far as I can tell there's no way to get a native look-and-feel renderer for the resultant header -- and a native appearance is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single column JTable.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't find a good way to allow each cell to have a different height.

Comment: @stuffy, use the setRowHeight() method of JTable.

Comment: Ah. I guess I'll have to manage the exact sizes manually then.